# How to dynamically display a simulated network topology in Java

Tags: java, simulation, topology

Specifically, I am working on a network simulation tool written in Java (JNS).  Topology objects are Nodes (names, IPHandlers and IP addresses) and DuplexLinks (IP addresses for each end, bandwidth and delay).

I am looking for a way to dynamically display certain topology objects (star, ring, etc.) given differing numbers of nodes.  Are there any existing libraries that can do this already?

I want to achieve this without manually entering canvas locations during the simulation configuration.  I plan on animating events over the drawn topology using JNam (adjusted to work with JNS instead of ns-2).

Comment: I must admit, this is the first time I've posted here so if there is any other information that would be useful, please let me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=display+topology++in+java

Answer (score 0):

I used this: [jgraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html)
There is also: [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/)
This maybe helpfull: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670846/comparing-open-source-java-graph-drawing-frameworksjung-and-prefuse-for-drawin)

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Instead of using one of those tools, I simply implemented a sorting method and calculated equidistant points on a circle for each category using the sin() function.
            innerDiameter/2*Math.sin(2*i*Math.PI/numNodes)